# EditText with hint always visible

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is there a way to make EditText show hint even when the text is entered?

[image]

Comment: I have no code. The screenshot was taken on an iPhone. I'm looking for a solution on android.

Comment: Check this custom editText https://github.com/faradaj/PatternedEditText

Comment: This should work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/17517464/3518278

Comment: yes you can use setOnFocusChangeListener for that

Answer (score -2):

Check [TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout). You wrap your edit text inside and have a lot of options